how to rename file after export from filename sequential based on expression datatable in VB.NET
I'm Trying to to rename file image after export with datatable in VB.NET
I use library control LabelControl for .NET from BaiqiSoft
I have also asked Baiqisoft support and then he replied "this is the design behavior of our product." so the results of the export filename from the library are sequential .is there a solution I can rename after export image and also without mistakes I rename the filename based on expression datatable ? or another method?
Please Guide me
for more detailed documentation refer below link.
https://www.mysofttool.com/help/labeldesign/
Imports System.IO
Imports BaiqiSoft.LabelControl
Public Class Form1
    Private m_DataTable As DataTable
    Private Sub CreateDataTable()
        If m_DataTable IsNot Nothing Then Return
        m_DataTable = New DataTable
        'Columns
        m_DataTable.Columns.Add("ProductName", GetType(String))
        m_DataTable.Columns.Add("Barcode", GetType(String))
        m_DataTable.Columns.Add("Price", GetType(Single))
        m_DataTable.Columns.Add("LabelNumber", GetType(Integer))
        m_DataTable.Columns.Add("QTY", GetType(Integer))
        m_DataTable.Columns.Add("Filename", GetType(String), "ProductName +','+ Barcode")
        'Rows
        m_DataTable.Rows.Add("Mishi Kobe Niku", "845723054943", 96.0, 2, 1)
        m_DataTable.Rows.Add("Carnarvon Tigers", "246321456231", 61.5, 1, 1)
        m_DataTable.Rows.Add("Ipoh Coffee", "589412354786", 46.0, 3, 1)
        m_DataTable.Rows.Add("Aniseed Syrup", "457125463254", 10.0, 1, 1)
        m_DataTable.Rows.Add("Teatime Chocolate Biscuits", "232145674321", 9.2, 5, 1)
    End Sub
Private Sub Btnexport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btnexport.Click
        Dim theLabel As New LabelPrinting()
        theLabel.LicenseKey = ""
        theLabel.OpenLabel(Application.StartupPath & "\test.blf")
        Dim selectedRows As DataTable = m_DataTable.Clone
        selectedRows.Columns("Filename").Expression = Nothing : selectedRows.Columns("Filename").ReadOnly = False
        For Each row2 As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            Dim isselect As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(row2.Cells("checkboxcolumn").Value)
            If isselect Then
                Dim newRow As DataRow = selectedRows.NewRow()
                newRow("ProductName") = m_DataTable.Rows(row2.Index)("ProductName")
                newRow("Barcode") = m_DataTable.Rows(row2.Index)("Barcode")
                newRow("Price") = m_DataTable.Rows(row2.Index)("Price")
                newRow("LabelNumber") = m_DataTable.Rows(row2.Index)("LabelNumber")
                newRow("QTY") = m_DataTable.Rows(row2.Index)("QTY")
                newRow("Filename") = m_DataTable.Rows(row2.Index)("ProductName") + "," + m_DataTable.Rows(row2.Index)("Barcode") + ".png"
                selectedRows.Rows.Add(newRow)
                theLabel.Label.QuantityColumn = "QTY"
            End If
        Next row2
        theLabel.DataSource = selectedRows
        theLabel.ExportOptions.FileName = "test"
        theLabel.ExportOptions.Path = Application.StartupPath
        theLabel.ExportOptions.Quantity = QuantityOptions.AllRecords
        theLabel.ExportOptions.Format = ImageFormats.Png
        theLabel.ExportOptions.Resolution = 300
        theLabel.ExportImage()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CreateDataTable()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = m_DataTable
        Dim CheckedBoxColumn As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
        CheckedBoxColumn.Width = 40
        CheckedBoxColumn.Name = "checkboxcolumn"
        CheckedBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Check"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, CheckedBoxColumn)
    End Sub
End Class

Result from Code :
test1.png

test2.png

test3.png

test4.png

test5.png

It should be like this (Desired result):
Mishi Kobe Niku,845723054943.png
 
Carnarvon Tigers,246321456231.png
 
Ipoh Coffee,589412354786.png
 
Aniseed Syrup,457125463254.png
 
Teatime Chocolate Biscuits,232145674321.png

Is it possible that I can rename like this
test1.png >>>> Mishi Kobe Niku,845723054943.png

test2.png >>>> Carnarvon Tigers,246321456231.png

test3.png >>>> Ipoh Coffee,589412354786.png

test4.png >>>> Aniseed Syrup,457125463254.png

test5.png >>>> Teatime Chocolate Biscuits,232145674321.png



You should be able to rename the files afterwards, just map the original name with the desired new name, for example in a Dictionary(Of String, String):
Private Sub Btnexport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btnexport.Click
    Dim theLabel As New LabelPrinting()
    theLabel.LicenseKey = ""
    theLabel.OpenLabel(Application.StartupPath & "\test.blf")
    Dim selectedRows As DataTable = m_DataTable.Clone
    selectedRows.Columns("Filename").Expression = Nothing : selectedRows.Columns("Filename").ReadOnly = False
    
    Dim fileNameMapper = New Dictionary(Of String, String)(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    Dim fileCounter As Int32 = 0
    Dim fileName = "test"

    For Each row2 As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        Dim isselect As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(row2.Cells("checkboxcolumn").Value)
        If isselect Then
            Dim newRow As DataRow = selectedRows.NewRow()
            newRow("ProductName") = m_DataTable.Rows(row2.Index)("ProductName")
            newRow("Barcode") = m_DataTable.Rows(row2.Index)("Barcode")
            newRow("Price") = m_DataTable.Rows(row2.Index)("Price")
            newRow("LabelNumber") = m_DataTable.Rows(row2.Index)("LabelNumber")
            newRow("QTY") = m_DataTable.Rows(row2.Index)("QTY")
            newRow("Filename") = m_DataTable.Rows(row2.Index)("ProductName") + "," + m_DataTable.Rows(row2.Index)("Barcode") + ".png"
            selectedRows.Rows.Add(newRow)
            theLabel.Label.QuantityColumn = "QTY"

            fileCounter += 1 
            Dim originalName = $"{fileName}{fileCounter}.png"
            fileNameMapper.Add(originalName, newRow.Field(Of String)("Filename"))
        End If
    Next row2
    theLabel.DataSource = selectedRows
    theLabel.ExportOptions.FileName = fileName
    theLabel.ExportOptions.Path = Application.StartupPath
    theLabel.ExportOptions.Quantity = QuantityOptions.AllRecords
    theLabel.ExportOptions.Format = ImageFormats.Png
    theLabel.ExportOptions.Resolution = 300
    theLabel.ExportImage()
    RenameFiles(fileNameMapper, theLabel.ExportOptions.Path)
End Sub


The RenameFiles method is straightforward with little help of LINQ:
Private Sub RenameFiles(fileNameMapper As Dictionary(Of String,String), path As String)
    Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo(path)
    Dim files = dir.EnumerateFiles().
        Where(Function(fi) fileNameMapper.ContainsKey(fi.Name))
    For Each file In files
        Dim destination = IO.Path.Combine(file.Directory.FullName, fileNameMapper(file.Name))
        file.MoveTo(destination, true)
    Next
End Sub


@TimSchmelter , Thank you for your answer and sorry I was late replying. for this line code file.MoveTo(destination, True) I have an error Error BC30057 Too many arguments to 'Public Overloads Sub MoveTo(destFileName As String)' so I change to file.MoveTo(destination)  and for this line code fileNameMapper.Add(originalName, newRow.Field(Of String)("Filename")) I have an error  Additional information: An item with the same key has already been added. . Please Guide me

I used this overload of MoveTo, maybe you use an older.Net framework.

You have to use the debugger to see what's going wrong. You cant add multiple duplicate keys to a dictionary. So it seems in your code you reuse the dictiionary instead of creating it in the method or you dont incrememt the counter as i did.

@dlaksmi You need to change the line Dim originalName = $"{fileName}{++fileCounter}.png" to the two lines fileCounter +=1 Dim originalName = $"{fileName}{fileCounter}.png" because VB.NET doesn't have the ++ increment operator.

@AndrewMorton: interesting, so what does ++fileCounter do then? It doesn't modify the variable fileCounter like in C# but just return the result value?

@TimSchmelter , I used this overload of MoveTo, maybe you use an older.Net framework.  you are right, I use framework 4.8

@TimSchmelter , You have to use the debugger to see what's going wrong. You cant add multiple duplicate keys to a dictionary. So it seems in your code you reuse the dictiionary instead of creating it in the method or you dont incrememt the counter as i did.  I do it as you do and is it possible after I export the image file with the event button export and I do another event button (rename)

@AndrewMorton , You need to change the line Dim originalName = $"{fileName}{++fileCounter}.png" to the two lines fileCounter +=1 Dim originalName = $"{fileName}{fileCounter}.png" because VB.NET doesn't have the ++ increment operator.  Thanks for your response Still I'm experiencing the same error Additional information: An item with the same key has already been added.

@dlaksmi: changed my code to fix the issue as proposed by Andrew.

@TimSchmelter , Thank you for the update of the answer but I have an error  . This line Dim files = dir.EnumerateFiles(path).Where(Function(fi) fileNameMapper.ContainsKey(fi.Name)) error Additional information: Second path fragment must not be a drive or UNC name. Please Guide me

@dlaksmi You need to examine the value of path when it goes wrong. Can you see something wrong with it, for example illegal characters or something like two drive letters in it?

@TimSchmelter It would be possible to use Interlocked.Increment() to replace C#'s ++ post-increment operator. Possible, but not necessarily sensible.

@AndrewMorton , I change code from Dim files = dir.EnumerateFiles(path) to Dim files = dir.EnumerateFiles() . Problem solved Thank you for your help. And also your support is perfect

@TimSchmelter ,  I change code from Dim files = dir.EnumerateFiles(path) to Dim files = dir.EnumerateFiles() . Problem solved Thank you for your help . Your answer is perfect

@dlaksmi: sure, edited my code in the answer, you're welcome
